# Initialising a struct which is member of class

Tags: c++, class, struct, constructor

Here is my code:

```
...
#include "myheader.h"

myClass::myStruct Foo;

Foo.one = 1;
Foo.two = 2;

myClass myclass(Foo);
...
```

This is my class from the header file:

```
class myClass : baseClass{
public:
struct myStruct {
myStruct():
one(0),
two(0){}
int one;
int two;
};
myClass(const myStruct &mystruct);
};
```

But this is failing to compile, I think I am accessing the elements one and two in the proper way...
I get this error:

: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '.' token .

Where a m I going wrong?

Comment: Just a sidenote, I am not supposed to edit the header file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Foo.one = 1;
```

This is a statement, and it needs to go inside of a function or method definition. Statements cannot appear by themselves at the top level of a source file.

Try putting this code inside of a function, for example the entry point `main()`:

```
int main() {
    myClass::myStruct Foo;

    Foo.one = 1;
    Foo.two = 2;

    myClass myclass(Foo);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I placed it the Init() that the file already has. The earlier error went away. But now, I have a new error : ISO C++ forbids declaration of myStruct with no type\n expected ';' before '.'

Comment: @Codename I can't see your screen. Show some code, preferably in a new question since this is a new issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27684721/iso-c-forbids-declaration-of-mystruct-with-no-type