# ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'myStruct' with no type

Tags: c++, class, object

Here is my code DeviceClass.cpp:

```
...
#include "myHeader.h"

class DeviceClass : public DeviceClassBase {
private:
myClass::myStruct Foo;

Foo.one = 1;
Foo.two = 2;

myClass myclass(Foo);
...
};
```

This is myClass from the myHeader.h file:

```
class myClass : baseClass{
public:
struct myStruct {
myStruct():
one(0),
two(0){}
int one;
int two;
};
myClass(const myStruct &mystruct);
};
```

But this is failing to compile.
I get this error:

```
: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'myStruct' with no type
: error: expected ';' before '.' token
: error: 'myStruct' is not a type
: In member function 'virtual void DeviceClass::Init()':
: error: '((DeviceClass*)this)->DeviceClass::myclass' does not have class type
```

Where a m I going wrong?

I can only edit the DeviceClass.cpp file.

Comment: Doesn't look like valid C++. Assignment to instance variable in the middle of a class declaration???

Comment: Looks like you're approaching C++ by just typing in code and seeing what happens. This is the worst possible mistake you can do with this language; C++ for a few reasons simply cannot be learned by experimentation (no matter how smart you are), you need instead to read the manual first. Pick up a good book from http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/320726 and read it cover to cover. Your future you will be really grateful if you do this.

Comment: Why didn't you fix the problem from [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27683855/initialising-a-struct-which-is-member-of-class) first?

Answer (score 0):

Statements are not valid at the class level, they are only valid inside of functions or methods. Perhaps you meant to write a default constructor instead.  This is somewhat complicated by the fact that `myClass` has no default constructor (your explicitly-declared copy constructor suppresses the implicit default constructor), so you need to construct it in the initializer list.  You'll need a `static` factory function to create the required `myStruct` argument with the values you want.

```
class DeviceClass : public DeviceClassBase
{
public:
    DeviceClass();

private:
    static myClass::myStruct create_myStruct();

    myClass myclass;
};

myClass::myStruct DeviceClass::create_myStruct()
{
    myClass::myStruct Foo;

    Foo.one = 1;
    Foo.two = 2;

    return Foo;
}

DeviceClass::DeviceClass() : myclass(create_myStruct()) { }
```